# Determine sample size to evaluate the effect of my solution?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, sample-size

I am currently building a solution that can reduce the overall electric consumption of a household by remotely controlling some appliances *(for a period of 60 minutes)*.

And to prove that it works I will run a pilot program where I will equip a few people with my solution, and test it over the course of a few months. More specifically, we plan to test it 20-30 times over the course of 5 months.

However, I am struggling to understand what should be the minimum size so that my test has scientific value.
Indeed, the only data I will have is the overall consumption of a household, on 30-minute periods, and our effect may be quite low compared to the overall consumption *(for example if someone starts their oven during the time where we reduce the consumption of a few appliances we wouldn't be able to see the effect of our solution on that specific household)*

**As a result, how would you suggest determining the smallest sample to prove that what we do really works?**
Also, depending on that size we might be able to recruit twice as much users and simply have a control group that will believe they have our solution but won't use it

Thank you very much and have a great day,
Matthieu

Comment: I'm not sure you can even answer this question with the 30-minute interval design. Suppose your system simply turns off the refrigerator and water heater for 30 minutes, seemingly reducing electricity consumption during the time you're monitoring, but then loses all the savings by running the appliances twice as long when the test is finished.